# Multi threaded approach to convert TIFF to PDF using iText

Tags: java, multithreading, itext, tiff, futuretask

I am essentially trying to convert a tiff file to pdf using itext, which is fairly simple.
But from what I can see `TiffImage.getTiffImage` is taking a lot of time to execute for larger files.

My requirement is to use `FutureTask` and `ExecutorService` to provide a multi threaded solution. Here is my current code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.RandomAccessFileOrArray;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage;

public class ProcessTiffImage implements Callable<Image>{

    RandomAccessFileOrArray tiffFile;
    int pageNo;

    public ProcessTiffImage(RandomAccessFileOrArray tiffFile, int pageNo){
        this.tiffFile = tiffFile;
        this.pageNo = pageNo;
    }

    public Image call() throws Exception {
        Image image = TiffImage.getTiffImage(tiffFile, pageNo);

        return image;

    }

}
```

and the convert method is

```
public boolean convert(Document document) {

        int numOfThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()  ;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numOfThreads );
        List<FutureTask<Image>> taskList = new ArrayList<FutureTask<Image>>();
        List<Image> imageList = new ArrayList<Image>();

        for (int page = 1; page <= numOfPages; page++) {
            FutureTask<Image> futureTask = new FutureTask<Image>(new ProcessTiffImage(tiffFile, page));
            taskList.add(futureTask);
            service.execute(futureTask);
        }

        try {
            // Wait until all results are available
            for (FutureTask<Image> future : taskList) {

                imageList.add(future.get());
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        service.shutdown();


        boolean success = generatePdf(document, imageList);
        return success;
    }
```

But I'm getting a `NullPointerException` at `future.get()`. The problem is the execution is not waiting for TiffImage.getTiffImage(tiffFile, pageNo) to finish. Hence I'm unable to create the Image List.
Any help would be very much appreciated.

Stack Trace

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at com.app.convertor.TiffParser.convert(TiffParser.java:107)
    at com.app.start.TiffToPdf.main(TiffToPdf.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TIFFDirectory.getFieldAsLong(TIFFDirectory.java:467)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TIFFDirectory.getFieldAsLong(TIFFDirectory.java:477)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.getTiffImage(TiffImage.java:124)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.codec.TiffImage.getTiffImage(TiffImage.java:106)
    at com.app.processor.ProcessTiffImage.call(ProcessTiffImage.java:20)
    at com.app.processor.ProcessTiffImage.call(ProcessTiffImage.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Can you please post the full stack trace?

Comment: @chiastic-security edited the post

Comment: It's because `RandomAccessFileOrArray` isn't thread-safe. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be happening because `RandomAccessFileOrArray` **is not thread safe**.

The exception you're getting in the `future.get()` call is an underlying exception in the `TiffImage.getTiffImage()` call, and that seems to be happening because that method isn't happy with the TIFF data it's being passed. In particular, it's looking to get some field out, and it seems it's not there. Possibly image height or width?

But that's happening because the `RandomAccessFileOrArray` is being consumed in multiple threads. Every time one thread moves the pointer in the file, it screws up what the other threads are doing.

You need to use [`RandomAccessFileOrArray.createView()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/RandomAccessFileOrArray.html#createView%28%29) to get a new view of the file to pass to each thread:

```
Image image = TiffImage.getTiffImage(tiffFile.createView(), pageNo);
```

Comment: I understand your point, but what's weird is that if I debug this code in any standard IDE is works perfectly and is happy with the data I pass to the getTiffImage(). But running the same, is causing the issue. Thanks for the help though, will try putting in a try/catch to monitor the data.

Answer (score 3):

Don't create the `Future` yourself, ask the executor to create it for you,(ie: submit a `Callable`)

```
List<Future<Image>> taskList = new ArrayList<Future<Image>>();

 for (int page = 1; page <= numOfPages; page++) {
     Future<Image> futureTask = service.submit(new ProcessTiffImage(tiffFile, page));
     taskList.add(futureTask);
 }

for (Future<Image> future : taskList) {
   imageList.add(future.get());
}
```

Note: consider using [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) instead.

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: ExceptionConverter: java.io.EOFException
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
 at com.app.convertor.TiffParser.convert(TiffParser.java:118)
 at com.app.start.TiffToPdf.main(TiffToPdf.java:40)

Comment: Yes, this is sensible advice, but I don't think it solves OP's problem.